# How to create JSON Array using two fields from a ResultSet?

Tags: java, mysql, json, jsp, arraylist

I want to generate an ArrayList of objects for making it a source for jquery UI Autocomplete. However, this following function of mine is throwing error if I fiddle with additional values in an entry

```
public ArrayList getUserData()
{

    ArrayList buffer = new ArrayList();
          try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");                     
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chbs?" + "user=root&password=xxx");                              
            Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from users");
            while(rs.next())
            {
            buffer.add('"{' + rs.getString("users.Employee_ID") +  '"' + rs.getString("users.Employee_Name") + '}"');
        }
            return buffer;
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
 return buffer;
}
```

I want the result like this

```
 data = [
    {
        empid:"xyz111",
        empName:"Hello"
    },
{
        empid:"xyz222",
        empName:"Hi"
    }
];
```

But, I am getting

```
data = ["xyz111"Hello","xyz222"Hi"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, it isn't good idea to manipulate/construct JSON manually. Instead, you should make use of some library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to do this job.

What you are getting is just concatenated `String`s which is added to `List`. Now, to get what you are expecting, you need to create a POJO class, which will hold the `empid` and `empName`. Then, create list of this object and pass it to the `ObjectMapper`.

Example :

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();

 while(rs.next())
 {
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setEmpId(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("users.Employee_ID")));
    emp.setEmpName(rs.getString("users.Employee_Name"));
    empList.add(emp);
 }
 //Object to JSON in String
 String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(empList);
```